# Beginner C programs

Tags: c

Does anyone know of a list of C programs that can be practised by beginners?

Comment: Err, buy a C book? K&R2.

Comment: how much have you studied yet? Do you want specific questions?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use something from here http://www.simonhuggins.com/courses/cbasics/index.htm

but i can recomend you this book http://www.computersciencelab.com/Deitel.htm there are lot of samples

Answer (score 1):

Sphere Online Judge has a ton of problems at many difficulty levels. The neat thing is you can submit them after you're done to have the server run the program and tell you if you got the right results or not.

http://www.spoj.pl/problems/classical/

Explanation of the different categories of problems:

http://www.spoj.pl/tutorials/USERS/#choose